# NGINX rewrite rule for dynamic URL

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting

I was wondering about how to write a correct rewrite for nginx as it fails everytime.

I have a page that can either be visited without any action (http://foo.bar/praemienshop/) or with a parameter inside the url which then triggers an action (http://foo.bar/praemienshop/1). The parameter should always be numeric. If possible, the ending slash should be optional if no parameter is given.
This is what I tryed:

```
location /praemienshop {
        rewrite ^/praemienshop(|/)([0-9]+/.*?)?$ /index.php?url=praemienshop&item=$1;
}
```

Iam able to open foo.bar/praemienshop but everytime I open foo.bar/praemienshop/3 (or any other numeric value) it just throws a 404 not found.

I'm neither really good at writing regexp nor do I really understand completely how rewriting works in nginx. I had it working in IIS, but importing it to nginx is quite hard somehow.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `$1` is the first capture `(|/)` - you should try `$2`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Richard. But this doesnt fix it. It still throws a 404 if I add a digit (ex: foo.bar/praemienshop/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you currently have it, you are using the wrong capture and also the regular expression does not match the URI. Try:

```
rewrite ^/praemienshop(?:/([0-9]+))?$ /index.php?url=praemienshop&item=$1;
```

In the above regular expression, the `(?:` is a non-capturing group.

See [this useful resource on regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html).

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked like a charm! I still have much to learn regarding regex ;-)

Comment: I have one more question Richard, how can I rewrite a url that if a user enters a url with an ending .gif, the .gif gets removed and the file name gets rewritten in a parameter just like the above example?

Comment: Constructions like `^(.*)\.gif$` will capture the URI minus the extension.